# Insert a value into database based on Session's User ID

Tags: php, session, insert

Attempting to insert a Score based on the User's Session ID and POST , I've set up the database to use the UserID as a foreign key constraint but dont know how to do an insert query.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiRW9.png)

Database Values ^^

My attempt below

```
<?php
include("php/functions.php");
include('connections/conn.php');
$userID = $_SESSION["userID"];
//echo "all good here";
$newsoanxscore = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['socanxscore']);
$insertquery = "INSERT INTO socanxscore(socialanxietyscore)" . "VALUES('$newsoanxscore')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $insertquery) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

My insert form

```
 <form action="insertsoanxietyscore.php" method="post">
        Insert your score <input type="number" name="socanxscore" /><br><br>
        <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here that may be helpful.

Firstly, you are not passing the user ID into your insert query. which can be written in this case as.

```
$insertquery = "INSERT INTO socanxscore(socialanxietyscore, UserId) VALUES('$newsoanxscore', '$userID')";
```

Secondly, please take the time to explore prepared queries to prevent SQL injection when passing end-user input to a database table. You may find the following resource useful.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

go for this:

```
     <?php
    session_start();
    include("php/functions.php");
    include('connections/conn.php');
    $userID = $_SESSION["userID"];
    if(isset($_POST["socanxscore"]))
    {
        $query=INSERT INTO socanxscore(socialanxietyscore) VALUES('$newsoanxscore') WHERE userID=$userID";


        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $insertquery) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}

else
{
ehco "error";
}

    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: Why go for this? There are at least five issues with this answer. (Invalid PHP being the first)

Comment: @anuragpandey FYI, you are missing an " at the start of the SQL query. You have also mistyped "echo". And the query for the SQL insert is also invalid, as you wouldn't use a where clause for an INSERT as you are creating a new record, not modifying an existing record.

Comment: You also have opened the user to sql injections by removing the `mysqli_real_escape_string` (which also is not the best practice).

Comment: nice and hope that u get ur solutiion